# A midi file exits but can't load using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I ran the following code:

```
import pygame
import os

music_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "midi.mid")
print(os.path.exists(music_file))
pygame.mixer.music.load(music_file)
```

The output is:

```
True

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-cd8bc226cd05> in <module>()
      4 music_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "midi.mid")
      5 print(os.path.exists(music_file))
----> 6 pygame.mixer.music.load(music_file)

error: /etc/timidity.cfg: No such file or directory
```

Why?Is it a bug of pygame?
I want to play midi.

Comment: print music_file

Comment: /home/marimo/Desktop/midi/midi.mid

Comment: well but the error is "error: /etc/timidity.cfg: No such file or directory" read it again

Comment: This looks like the problem reported [here](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/343). You could try reinstalling timidity or ensuring the config file `/etc/timidity.cfg` exists.

Answer (score 1):

i can solve this issues on the following page,
I execute this commands.
I hope this can be useful for you.

```sh
sudo apt-get install freepats
sudo apt-get install timidity
```

for more info:
https://medium.com/@karthik_ak/pygame-midi-file-issue-on-ubuntu-16-04-2dcfc776ede9

Comment: Please consider adding context for links provided on the answers as well as further explanations on how your answer solves the problem.